# Do Killstreak Kits for Stock Weapons also work on 'Australium' versions of weapons?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I recently got an Australium Minigun and I want to apply a Specialized Killstreak Kit to it (one I found on the market). The one I found on the market is called a "Specialized Killstreak Minigun Kit", as I could not find an "Specialized Killstreak Australium Minigun Kit".

This is obviously for the stock minigun but would it also work with an Australium weapon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would. Applying a killstreak kit to **any** weapon will give that weapon that killstreak. The reason for this is that strange, australium and killstreak are all separate attributes so don't "overwrite" each other.

Comment: In order for this explanation to make sense, you'd have to know that Australium weapons do not have their own entry in the TF2 item schema.